# How to confige c3p0 onnection pool in spring-data-jpa?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, connection-pooling

As a default, Hikari is a connection pool in spring-data-jpa. How to configure the c3p0 connection pool in spring-data-jpa instead of Hikari?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-data-jpa uses Hikari (not spring data JPA). BTW, Why problems do you observe with Hikari ?

Comment: I have decided to make a microservice application and I want to use the spring cloud framework with spring boot. Before starting, I must learn deeply about concepts and I declared some challenges such as changing the connection pool. That's it :D

Answer (score 2):

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
       <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
   </dependency>
```